# Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime: Reading string with ClrMD ClrObject

Tags: c#, .net-core, diagnostics

I'm using the Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime library.

I have an object: ClrObject obj = heap.GetObject(ptr);
And I can read:

```
    int length = obj.ReadField<int>("_stringLength");
    char firstCharacter = obj.ReadField<char>("_firstChar");
```

of a System.String object.

When I know the length and I can read the first character, how can I read the complete string?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ClrObject.AsString` in ClrMD 2.0.